# hg - what to do when hg push times out

Tags: mercurial

UPDATE - I'm probably being daft, see my last update below.

I just did a `hg push` and it timed out, and now when I try `hg push` again I get a message 'no changes found', however I can see in the target repo that all but a few of the changes didn't make it to the repo. How can I push my changes to that repo?

The history behind this is I'm migrating from SVN to Mercurial (bitbucket). I've done the following:

- Used svnsync to get a local copy of the SVN repository.
- Created a new repo within bitbucket
- Cloned the repo to my local machine
- Done `svnadmin convert` from my local SVN repo to my local Hg repo
- Run `hg push` to push the changes to bitbucket

The last command prompts me for HTTP authorisation, then says 'searching for changes', no output for >15 mins, then output 'abort: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out'. Full process was:

```
C:\dev\sandbox\svn_to_hg\dev_hg>hg push
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: my_login
password:
pushing to https://bitbucket.org/my_login/dev
searching for changes
abort: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out

C:\dev\sandbox\svn_to_hg\dev_hg>hg push
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: my_login
password:
pushing to https://bitbucket.org/my_login/dev
searching for changes
no changes found
```

It seems that because there are so many changes it's taking too long between HTTP auth and when it actually pushes the changes, or something like that, and probably if I set up SSH keys it'd not need to cache the HTTP authentication so it wouldn't time out. Any ideas if that's correct? Regardless, I still need to know how to push these changes that hg now thinks have already been pushed.

In my bitbucket repository there are about 20 changesets from SVN from a few years ago, but there should be several thousand.

UPDATE:

hg out gives me this:

```
C:\dev\sandbox\svn_to_hg\dev_hg>hg out
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: my_login
password:
comparing with https://bitbucket.org/my_login/dev
searching for changes
no changes found
```

Looking at the repo using TortoiseHg repo browser shows there is tons of stuff there.

UPDATE:

Perhaps I'm being daft, now when I look at the repo within bitbucket it does seem that there are lots of changesets. But what timed out? Should I worry that all my changesets didn't make it to the server?

Comment: Show us `hg out` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all changesets did make it - i.e. answer is to retry and then trust Mercurial.